# switchMap to switchMapTo

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Currently I have this piece of code

```
this.save()
  .pipe(switchMap(() => this.unlock()))
  .subscribe(...);
```

`save` and `unlock` implementations are

```
private save(): Observable<void> {
  return new Observable(subscriber => {
    this.xmlService.save(..., () => {
      ...       
      subscriber.next();
      subscriber.complete();
    });
  });
}

private unlock(): Observable<void> {
  return this.httpService.unlock(this.id);
}
```

---

Being that `unlock` doesn't really depend on a value `save` returns, could I just use `switchMapTo`?

```
this.save()
  .pipe(switchMapTo(this.unlock()))
  .subscribe(...);
```

Or have I misunderstood how the `*To` variant behaves?

Comment: Yeah, you use `switchMapTo` when you don't care about the upstream data, only emissions as a signal.

Comment: @ritaj However, if `save` doesn't emit, I'm creating an `Observable` for nothing, while with `switchMap` it is lazy

Comment: Then you could defer it's creation. `switchMapTo(defer(() => this.unlock()))`. But nothing wrong with using `swtichMap` either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`switchMapTo` is identical to `switchMap` except that it takes an observable instead of a callback function.
See the source code:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/switchMapTo.ts#L56

Comment: In my case the function reference doesn't seem to "work". `error TS2345: Argument of type '() => Observable<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObservableInput<void>'.
  Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type '() => Observable<void>' but required in type 'Iterable<void>'`.

Comment: Another question. Is it safe to reuse the `Observable` instance obtained by calling `unlock()`?

Comment: try `switchMapTo<void, void, void>(func)`, but strange that you get a type error.

Comment: Might be because I'm using the `strict` flag?

Comment: It is safe to reuse observables, but as long as you understand how subscribe works.

Comment: Error goes away using `switchMapTo<any>(this.unlock)`.

Comment: I would not use `any` in this case. Not sure why you're getting the type error. Maybe open another question for that if you want.

Comment: Okay! Thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure a function can be passed as input? `InteropObservable` signature is `export type InteropObservable<T> = { [Symbol.observable]: () => Subscribable<T>; };` and there is no other type which is compatible with a function.

Comment: @LppEdd oh crap. You're totally right. It takes an observable as the parameter. Sorry that's my bad.